# How do I set up the CNAME record to use my freenom domain name with Google sites?

Tags: cname

I have the TXT record set up properly for my Google verification ie, Name=www ttl=3600 target=google-site-verification=sadlfadsasdadsfad This seems to have satisfied Google and has approved the domain name.

These are [the instructions that Google gives](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867) to create the necessary CNAME to point the domain name to the actual site being hosted by `sites.google.com`

> - Go to your domain host.
> - Create a new CNAME entry.
> - Enter the subdomain name, for example, the "www" of `www.example.com`.
>
> Type in the host name `ghs.googlehosted.com`. This will point your URL
> to your Google site.

I have tried:

- name = www
- ttl = 3600
- target = `ghs.googlehosted.com`

to no avail it doesn't work, however the `freenom.com` host seems to think it's OK and Google accepts that my domain is correct.

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I've done many searches for an exact example of how it is done, but, I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are typing ghs.googlehosted.com into the CNAME destination without any surrounding spaces.